# Unsupported grant type for password strategy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, doorkeeper

Update: This is only happening in my existing specs. I can run the app and authenticate successfully. Did something change in the spec setup between my versions of Doorkeeper?

I have an existing app that has been working and just upgraded to Rails (4.2.6 -> 5.1.3), Ruby (2.3.0 -> 2.4.1), Doorkeeper (1.4.1 -> 4.2.6).

I use the password (ROPC) strategy and cannot get it to work after upgrading. The error returned is:

```
"error":"unsupported_grant_type"
"error_description":"The authorization grant type is not supported by the authorization server."
```

My doorkeeper.rb initializer has: `grant_flows %w(password)`

I tried adding `Doorkeeper.configuration.token_grant_types << "password"` per the wiki.

I can step through the code and can see the `password` flow being added from `grant_flows` but when the spec tries to auth it no longer has `password` and raises the exception.

Any ideas on how I can get this working?

Comment: Followed this link and resolved issue.
https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Using-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-flow

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass `grant_type` with your request.

```
{
  grant_type: "password",
  username: "xxxxxxxxxx",
  password: "1234567890"
}
```

Comment: This is how I'm passing the request, does not work. I did discover the when I run the app everything works as expected but the existing specs are what's failing.